# Find out user's device info from OAuth2 Token in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api

I am currently developing a mobile app with a Web API MVC in ASP.NET using standard OAuth2 authentication token. Currently to receive a token for a registered user, the following URL needs to be called https://example.com/Token. If passed, the user is returned a standard token with additional validation. However I do not seem to have access to do anything else with the user's request when https://example.com/Token and I would like to find out user's device info that the token is assigned to.

I have a few questions with regards to token authorization:

- Is there a few to customize function that is called by https://example.com/Token?
- If not, should a user call https://example.com/Account/Login where I will put a wrapper around /Token and call it myself.
- What is a standard way of finding a device info for a given token?
- Also, I wonder if there is a way to be providing a non-expiring token so that a mobile user doesn't need to logging every time the token expires? I am sure there is a standard and safe way of handling it.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: have a look at http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: "non-expiring token" yes, you can with refresh token. Also, You can have offline access. For example Google: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2